# Concurrent processing of web service calls within a mule flow

Tags: mule

**Rephrased the question** - 
I have a requirement where in, within an individual mule flow, I have to make 3 web service calls (S1, S2, S3).

```
<flow>
 <Service1>
 <Service2>
 <Service3>
</flow>
```

My requirement is to call Service1 & wait for it's completion (or handle error if unsuccessful & return) AND then fire Service2 & Service3 concurrently/simultaneously. I want to wait for Service1's response as my calls to Service2 & Service3 use part of the response from Service1 as input. So my mule flow should wait for response from Service1 before firing Service2 & Service3. But if & when Service1 succeeds, it should call both Service2 & Service3 at the same time. 
Even if one of Service2 & Service3 fails, I want to continue and not fail/error for the caller of this flow.

Any kind of sample code/ link would be great.

Comment: Your question is little confusing. Is it running services parallel or sequential(one after other)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following kind of design if you want to call 3 services one after other and failure of any service should not impact the remaining flow.

```
<flow name="main_flow">
    <flow-ref name="private_flow_call_to_service_1"></flow-ref>
    <flow-ref name="private_flow_call_to_service_2"></flow-ref>
    <flow-ref name="private_flow_call_to_service_3"></flow-ref>
</flow>

<flow name="private_flow_call_to_service_1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <!-- call service 1  -->
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <!-- Catch and handle any error or failure while making call to service 1 -->
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>

<flow name="private_flow_call_to_service_2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <!-- call service 2  -->
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <!-- Catch and handle any error or failure while making call to service 2 -->
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>

<flow name="private_flow_call_to_service_3" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <!-- call service 3  -->
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <!-- Catch and handle any error or failure while making call to service 3 -->
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mule scatter-gather component is used for executing multiple flows concurrently. 
This component has been introduced in Mule 3.5
reference :-
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Scatter-Gather

To make sure that failure of one flow doesn't affect other, you can wrap the flows in `<async/>` block